# Entry level questions about the trig function sine

Tags: trigonometry

**Background**

In school they teach that: $$sin(\theta) = \frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$$

---

I'm confused because the argument $\theta$ is not in the RHS. It almost feels like the expression should be: $$sin(\theta, opposite,hypotenuse) = \theta*0+\frac{opposite}{hypotenuse}$$

**Question 1:**

Can you clarify why the LHS and RHS of $sin(\theta) = o/h$ reference totally different variables?

---

I'm looking for a "nice" formula for the function $sin(\theta)$. For example,the formula for distance is "nice":  $d(x,y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ and this is a formula that makes total sense to me.

I know about this approximation if $x$ is in radians: $sin(x) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!} x^{2n+1}$

**Question 2:**

Is it correct to say there is no "nice" function of sine? Why not?

[Edit: My own definition of "nice" is very arbitrary and not precise. If you were a beginner again of trigonometry, how would you explain what $sin(\theta)$ is in terms of $\theta$ only?]

---

Thank you for your help and patience!!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I am still not clear as to what "counts" as "nice".  The question, then, is unclear.

Comment: $\sin(\theta)$ is the ratio opposite/hypotenuse with respect to an angle $\theta$ in any right triangle where $\theta$ is an angle. The triangle used doesn't matter as long as it is a right triangle and it has $\theta$ as an angle, since all right triangles with angle $\theta$ are "scaled" versions of one another, making the ratio opposite/hypotenuse constant.

Comment: $\sin^2 \theta + \cos^2 \theta = 1$ is pretty nice.  (Equivalent to the Pythagorean Theorem). As is $\sin \theta = \pm\sqrt{1-\cos^2 \theta}$ (which is just a variation of the first identity.)

Comment: Sorry about that, I put "nice" in quotes where "nice" is defined as "easy for my newb brain" which I know is not very precise. If you put yourself in the shoes of a beginner, other formulas like $a^2 + b^2 = c^2$ seem much simpler. The only expression of $sin(x)$ I could find is the approximation I referenced above that adds an infinite amount of terms...

Comment: $\sin \theta = \mathbb{Im} e^{i\theta} $ I guess.  Nice isn't really a well defined property.  I like to think of coordinates on a unit circle.

Comment: @amWhy that is true I would agree with that! I was hoping to find a way to calculate $sin(\theta)$ almost like a calculator would. For example, since I am a beginner, I'm trying to improve my understanding of $sin$, and it doesn't help as much to put in $cos$ as the definition of $sin$. And I know calculators use a specific algorithm but it's interesting to me that a kind of approximation by summing a bunch of stuff is required.

Comment: You can visuailze the sine as the $y-$coordinate of a point along the unit circle that is $\theta$ degrees rotated counterclockwise from the positive-x axis.

Comment: @Karl, that is interesting I will look into that. You're right, nice is not well defined at all. From a math beginner standpoint it just seems that sin is a "simple" concept with lengths of sides but the formula is more complex. I guess that's just the way it is

Comment: I suspect (I don't know ) that a calculator would use the series definition you provided.  I understand that to be a definition of $\sin$ as opposed to an approximation.

Comment: @Karl Calculators probably indeed use different approximations. Chebyschev polynomials are a pretty standard way to do this theoretically; I don't know whether they're actually used in practice.

Comment: Thought they might.  I'm pretty sure you could define $\sin$ as the solution to a differential equation with boundary certain conditions.  I suspect the really issue here is thinking of a function as a machine that processes an input rather that associating two things.

Comment: @AirConditioner yes your explanation does make sense. I was just looking for a formula references $\theta$ only. For example, as a beginner learning about the distance formula from the origin of $(x,y)$ then I would want to know the formula in terms of $x$ and $y$ to build my understanding. It seems like for sine, the formula that references the angle only (and not lengths of sides) comes later in the learning process...

Comment: @Karl your point about me looking for a function as a machine of an input is dead on. I feel like if someone is learning about sine for the first time then it wouldn't be so unreasonable to want to see the machine that takes $\theta$ and calculates a number using $\theta$ only, instead of the association of sides. Anyway thanks for your insights.

Comment: About the 'nice' function, sine is not a function we can calculate in the same sense of the examples you gave for simple functions, but if you want functions that only uses the variable we can construct the fraction:$$\sin(x)=\frac{x}{1+\frac{x^2}{2\cdot 3-x^2+...}}$$ Although the general form of this fraction is not so simple, this form is called generalized continued fraction. We can also define sine with imaginary numbers:$$\sin(z)=\frac{e^{iz}-e^{-iz}}{2i}$$

Comment: @Holo Thanks for the examples and for entertaining my imprecise definition of "nice." I suppose when I look at the graph of sine (the wave), it makes sense that you can't express it as "nicely" as the distance formula which is a line. Expressing a simple parabola like $f(x) = x^2$ is "nice" but a wave is more "complicated" than a parabola. Anyway, I suppose to the universe it's all "nice" and totally obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 1: if you want $\theta$ to appear on the right-hand side, I think the following is much more natural, but it's completely unhelpful.

Write $\mathrm{opp}(\theta, t)$ for the length of the side opposite from the angle $\theta$ when the length of the adjacent side in a right-angled triangle is $t$.

Write $\mathrm{hyp}(\theta, t)$ for the length of the hypotenuse when the length of the adjacent side is $t$.

Then $$\sin(\theta) = \frac{\mathrm{opp}(\theta, t)}{\mathrm{hyp}(\theta, t)}$$
for any $t > 0$.

Comment: Thanks -- that actually does help me and answers my question. Seeing a LHS and RHS reference totally different things made me uneasy but this makes sense. Although I agree they should teach it as opposite / hypotenuse.